# Sql return all rows from parent table where criteria match from another child of a child table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

**Doc_group**

- id
- name

**doc_type**

- id
- doc_group_id
- name

**Doc**

- id
- doc_type_id
- name
- date

I would like to retrieve only rows from Doc_group where all of its doc have date less than 90 days.

Example:
**Doc_group**

```
+-----------------+
| id | name       |
+-----------------+
| 1 | doc_group_1 |
+-----------------+
| 2 | doc_group_2 |
+-----------------+
| 3 | doc_group_3 |
+-----------------+
```

**Doc_type**

```
+--------------------------------+
| id| name        | doc_group_id | 
+--------------------------------+
| 1 | doc_type_1  | 1            |
+--------------------------------+
| 2 | doc_type_2  | 1            |
+--------------------------------+
| 3 | doc_type_2  | 2            |
+--------------------------------+
```

**Doc**:

```
+---------------------------------------+
| id| name   | doc_type_id  | date      |
+---------------------------------------+
| 1 | doc_1  | 1            |01/10/2012 |
+---------------------------------------+
| 2 | doc_2  | 2            |01/9/2012  |
+---------------------------------------+
| 3 | doc_3  | 3            |01/10/2012 |
+---------------------------------------+
| 4 | doc_4  | 3            |26/07/2014 |
+---------------------------------------+
```

Result:
Only doc_group_1 should be returned as all of its doc is less than 90 days. 
doc_group_2 does not qualify as doc_4 is not less than 90 days
**Doc_group**

```
+-----------------+
| id | name       |
+-----------------+
| 1 | doc_group_1 |
+-----------------+
```

I tried group by, but I can't get the result I want.

Thanks

Comment: Create a SQLFiddle please. it would be easier an most attractive to us

Comment: I just updated the question. I tried SQLFiddle but I couldn't get it going.

Comment: Please show the SQL statement(s) that you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the query that you're looking for:

```
SELECT DG.*
FROM Doc_group DG
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT D.id
                 FROM Doc D
                 WHERE D.doc_group_id = DG.id
                    AND D.date < DATEADD(DAY, -90, GETUTCDATE()))
```

That's a solution in T-SQL, I'm not sure about the MySQL version.
Hope that this will help you.

After a quick search, here is the MySQL version of the query:

```
 SELECT DG.*
    FROM Doc_group DG
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT D.id
                     FROM Doc D
                     WHERE D.doc_group_id = DG.id
                        AND D.date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY))
```

I don't have any MySQL database to test this query but it should work ;-)

Comment: Nice, I wasn't sure about the MySQL version. Good news that this helps you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
select dg.id, dg.name
from Doc_group dg 
where dg.id not in
(
    select d.doc_group_id 
    from Doc d 
    where d.date NOT BETWEEN DATEDIFF(NOW() - 90 days) AND NOW()
)
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not work for me, I want to return only document group where all of its document are less than 90 days.

Comment: @momigi ok, I think I understand what you are after. I have updated the query to return ONLY document group where ALL of its document are less than 90 days

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM Doc_group DG 
INNER JOIN Type_group TG   ON  DG.ID = TG.doc_group_id
INNER JOIN Doc        D    ON  DG.doc_group_id = D.doc_group_id
WHERE D.date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 90 DAY AND NOW()
```

Comment: you should use CURDATE() when its days... cut out the time

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want,
but try this :

```
SELECT dg.*
FROM Doc_group AS dg
  INNER JOIN Doc AS d ON dg.id = d.doc_group_id
WHERE d.date BEETWEEN DATEDIFF(NOW() - 90 days) AND NOW()
```